# How I can select / sort dates by period intervals?

Tags: sql, time, intervals

For ex:

If we have in table records like:

```
25/06/2009
28/12/2009
19/02/2010
16/04/2011
20/05/2012
```

I want to split/select this dates according to 6 month intervals starting from current date.
result should be like:
0-6 month from now: first record 
7-12 month from now: second record
...

It will be much apreciated if you make this simple as I made it very stupid and complicated like:

```
declare variable like t1=curdate()+6 
t2=curdate()+12
```

...

then selected records to fit between curdate() and t1, then t1 and t2 etc.

Thanks,

r.

Answer (score 1):

CORRECTION:  Had it backwards, Need to use Modulus, not integer division -  sorry...

If MonthCount is a calculated value which counts the number of months since a specific Dec 31, and mod is modulus division (output the remainder after dividing)

```
Select [Column list here] 
From Table
Group By Case When MonthCount Mod 12 < 6 
         Then 0 Else 1 End
```

In SQL Server, for example, you could use the DateDiff Function

```
Select [Column list here] 
From Table
Group By Case When DateDiff(month, myDateColumn, curdate) % 12 < 6 
         Then 0 Else 1 End
```

( in SQL Server the percent sign is the modulus operator )

This will group all the record into buckets which each contain six months of data

Comment: I think the point is that he doesn't want to run it from specifc Jan->June & July-Dec periods, but the 6 month periods are calculated on the fly from the current date. so from todays date, the previous and next period would be 
2008-11-27 => 2009-05-27 AND
2009-05-27 => 2009-11-27

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (DATEDIFF(MONTH, thedate, GETDATE()) / 6) AS semester,
       SUM(receipt)
FROM thetable
GROUP BY semester
ORDER BY semester
```

the key idea is grouping and ordering by the expression that gives you the "semester".

Answer (score 0):

This question really baffled me, cos I couldn't actually come up with a simple solution for it. Damn.

Best I could manage was an absolute bastardization of the following where you create a Temp Table, insert the "Periods" into it, join back to your original table, and group off that.

Assume your content table has the following

```
ID int
Date DateTime
Counter int
```

And you're trying to sum all the `counter`'s in six month periods

```
DECLARE @min_date datetime
select @min_date = min(date) from test

DECLARE @max_date datetime
select @max_date = max(date) from test


DECLARE @today_a datetime
DECLARE @today_b datetime
set @today_a = getdate()
set @today_b = getdate()

CREATE TABLE #temp (startdate DateTime, enddate DateTime)

WHILE @today_a > @min_date
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp (startDate, endDate) VALUES (dateadd(month, -6, @today_a), @today_a)
    SET @today_a = dateadd(month, -6, @today_a)
END
WHILE @today_b < @max_date
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #temp (startDate, endDate) VALUES (@today_b, dateadd(month, 6, @today_b))
    SET @today_b = dateadd(month, 6, @today_b)
END

SELECT * FROM #temp

SELECT 
    sum(counter), 
    'Between ' + Convert(nvarchar(10), startdate, 121) + ' => ' +  Convert(nvarchar(10), enddate, 121) as Period
FROM test t
    JOIN #Temp ht
        ON t.Date between ht.startDate AND ht.EndDate
GROUP BY 
    'Between ' + Convert(nvarchar(10), startdate, 121) + ' => ' +  Convert(nvarchar(10), enddate, 121)

DROP TABLE #temp
```

I really hope someone can come up with a better solution my brain has obviously melted.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're attempting to accomplish, but you could use the DATEDIFF function to distinguish the ranging of each record:

```
SELECT t.MonthGroup, SUM(t.Counter) AS TotalCount
FROM (    
      SELECT Counter, (DATEDIFF(m, GETDATE(), Date) / 6) AS MonthGroup
      FROM Table
     ) t
GROUP BY t.MonthGroup
```

This would create a sub query with an expression that expresses the date ranging group you want.  It would then group the sub-query by this date ranging group and you can then do whatever you want with the results.

Edit: I modified the example based on your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL Server:

```
SELECT *,
    (
        FLOOR
        (
            (
                DATEDIFF(month, GETDATE(), date_column)
                - CASE WHEN DAY(GETDATE()) > DAY(date_column) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ) / 6.0
        ) * 6
    ) AS SixMonthlyInterval
FROM your_table
```

If you're using MySQL:

```
SELECT *,
    (
        FLOOR
        (
            (
                ((YEAR(date_column) - YEAR(CURDATE())) * 12)
                + MONTH(date_column) - MONTH(CURDATE())
                - CASE WHEN DAY(CURDATE()) > DAY(date_column) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ) / 6.0
        ) * 6
    ) AS SixMonthlyInterval
FROM your_table
```